# How to set the order for the unit tests to run in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, vs-unit-testing-framework

I've written many unit tests in a file.
The problem is they don't run in order.
I first make an entry to the database in one method and delete the same entry in another method.
Insert() appears before Remove() in my test file.
But still Remove() runs first and hence I am not able to execute the test cases effectively since it won't find the entry. Reason could be Remove() takes less execution time than Insert()
Can we set the sequence to the test cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix the test names with character alphabetically
like
aTestSomething
bTestAnotherThing

:)

better way

[How to order methods of execution using Visual Studio to do integration testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684408/how-to-order-methods-of-execution-using-visual-studio-to-do-integration-testing)

Comment: Thanks. that works. I've unit tests written in different files. Is there an option to run the units tests one file at a time. Now what is happening is when I give run->'All Tests' it runs units tests from all the files.