# Arrange UI test processing sequence

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, appium

I have more than 50 UI `@Test` (unit test using VS 2010) functions that execute using `Appium`. I have written the `test-cases` in a sequential way, starting from *login* and ending with *logout*.

However, my problem is when I start to execute these test cases, they do not run in the coded sequence. For example, `logout` can start before `login` and so it will fail. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: which testing framework are you using??

Comment: by testing framework i meant in which have you designed your test? eg `junit`, `testng` etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved when I clean the Visual Studio solution and rebuild the project again

Why clean affect [Form Jon Skeet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3095935/5957972)
Clean solution will remove the build artifacts from the previous build. If there are any other files in the build target directories (bin and obj) they may not be removed, but actual build artifacts are. I've seen behaviour for this vary - sometimes deleting fairly thoroughly and sometimes not - but I'll give VS the benefit of the doubt for the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `TestMethod` from visual studio an `Ordered Test` added to your project shall help you. While using `junit` or `test-ng`, one thing good to know is the `@Test` are supposedly de-coupled and able to execute independently. So the order of execution should not be the concern when you frame your test.

If this be forced by any chance that your method needs an order to execute you can use `dependsOnMethod` and `dependsOnGroup` using *junit* and have an additional capability termed `priority` in *testng*.
Good reads on this could be found here :

1. [Test methods in order junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4)
2. [Test methods in order testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669576/order-of-execution-of-tests-in-testng)
3. [Fix order in junit using RunWith](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-execution-order)
4. [Ordered test in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4688894/1746118)